# Guru Dattatreya Parayan

Tags: women, guru, festivals, dattatreya

Being a woman, can I read the whole Sri Guru Charitra, which is known as GuruDatta Parayana, in the coming Datta Jayanti (Festival) ?

In our home, my father used to read it every year by following all the rules. No woman has performed the Parayana yet in our home. But I want to do it.

Can I perform it? If not, what are the reasons?

[image: SadGuru]

Comment: Which book is read on that day? That book must have the info regarding who all are qualified to recite it. EDIT -- Ok the book name is Guru Charitra (found from Google).

Comment: `'Shrimat Gurucharitra'` is the name of book, from `Saraswati Book Company, Pune, Maharashtra`. It has been written there that Women should not read it. They can only hear from others. Even it has been said in book that no any bachelor lady can hear `Ved Mantra`. (otherwise they will get allegations of stealing anything)

Comment: Oh so if the book itself states that women shd not read it then what can be done? When ur father recites it u can hear which I think will be as good as reciting it urself.

Comment: Book says that Rethinking will be done about the issue of women reading. I don't know rethinking has done or not.

Comment: Some sites are saying that According to Vasudevanand Saraswati or  "Tembe Swami" women are not allowed to read.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar, ok, every book has its different opinion. It makes us confused....:-(

Comment: Sometimes I think that-- out society is male dominating. So, norms are created by males. So, they might have prohibited women to read `Guru Charitra Parayana` by specifying unnecessary rules.

Comment: @DhanashreeDeshpande - No this is not the reason. Datta Sampradaya people consider Guru-Charitra as veda. Also there are  very strict rules and regulations related to its Parayana. Generally women cant follow such strict rules for 7 days. Also there are some portions in the book like  Story of Brahmavadini Lopamudra  etc. which according to some scholars are not suitable for women. Although i am not from Datta-Sampradaya but know lots of people from my home town pune who regularly conduct parayana.

Comment: @DhanashreeDeshpande - there is abridged version of 'shri guru charitra'. I am told that it can be read by women either. You can get it in bookshop. It can be a golden mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just now downloaded the book [Sri Guru Charitra](http://saileelas.org/books/ShriGuruCharitra.doc). At the last section, the rules of properly reciting it are given and which are as follows:

> Namdharak- "Kindly tell me the procedure of week-reading and other
> rules to be followed during the week".
>
> Shri Siddha-"Shri Guru-Charitra can be read any time with pure mind.
> The credit of reading it in a week is still great. For this, one place
> and seat should be selected. Keep control on the senses during the
> week. Before starting the reading bow to God, Brahmin and elders.
> Worship the volume of "Shri GuruCharitra". One should complete 7
> chapters on the first day, read upto 18th chapter on the second day,
> upto 28th on the third day, upto 34th on the fourth day, upto 37th on
> the fifth day, upto 43rd on the sixth day and upto 52nd chapters on
> the seventh day. After reading, worship the volume and take light
> dinner. Some observe fast for the week; but if this is not possible
> have food of only one type of corn. On the eighth day, for completion
> of the week reading, take meals with a Brahmin couple and offer money
> as Dakshina. If the reading is done with devotion and pure heart, Shri
> Guru gives Darshan in dream and fulfills one's desires. The trouble of
> spirits and ghosts vanishes and one gets peace of mind. Namdharak
> again expressed to Shri Siddha Muni his gratitude for narrating the
> life of Shri Guru, which has made his life fortunate and enabled him
> to attain the bliss

So, it does not prohibit the women explicitly neither does it allow explicitly.

And, furthermore, this book, in one section, is having a part of Guru Gita too. And, it says that Guru Gita can be recited by everyone.

> **Recitation of Guru-Geeta**, gives one incentive power, develops one's
> qualities, destroys evil acts, makes good acts successful, removes
> fear of Grahas
>
> (planets), destroys evil dreams, **gives issues even to sterile women,**
> gives good luck to the married women (keep their husbands alive all
> their lives) and gives peace of mind. **If a widow reads Shri Guru-Geeta
> without object, she gets salvation. If she reads with desire, she will
> get a good husband in the next birth and all her miseries,
> difficulties and curses will perish.**

So, I am not sure why reading the book Guru Charitra will be forbidden for women.

Comment: in few books it has been mentioned. Within some book, it is not mentioned. I heard from few people (gents and ladies) that any lady should not read it. I don't know consequences. I believe on any worship with true mind and belief. But I asked here to know the exact reasons. Even shopkeeper, from whom I bought this book, told me that women should not read it.

Comment: Ok but the book itself has not mentioned anything like that. So,I am not sure how that tradition evolved @DhanashreeDeshpande

Comment: Here, I might have shown the book's rule details written on initial pages, But only rules are in 'Marathi' language.

Comment: Ok but those rules were probably added by the publishers. We need to chk whether the book itself has mentioned the prohibition, which apparently does not seem to be the case.. @DhanashreeDeshpande

Comment: Ok, That need to be check in specific `Adhyaya` (chapter) i.e. where it has been mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can read. I am reading gurucharitra from 3 years it also gave me so much peacefulness and benefits in my life.

Comment: The only condition is that women should not do parayana during menstruation period

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! Answers posted here must be backed up by sources. Please refer [how-to-answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) section to learn more.